# xtext generator expression getLeft and getRight

Tags: eclipse, expression, xtext

I'm trying to write a DSL via Xtext with which I can customize SQL. 
First I want to have a string representation of my query.
There I got stuck on the expressions. I created them after this example:  https://typefox.io/parsing-expressions-with-xtext.

```
Expression returns Expression: 
OrExpression;

OrExpression returns Expression:
AndExpression ({OrExpression.left=current} name="OR" right=AndExpression)*;

AndExpression returns Expression:
 NotExpression({AndExpression.left=current} name="AND" right=NotExpression)*;

NotExpression returns Expression:
 ComparisonExpression({NotExpression.left=current} name='NOT' right=ComparisonExpression)*;

ComparisonExpression returns Expression:
BitwiseOR({ComparisonExpression.left=current} name=cmpop right=BitwiseOR)*;

BitwiseOR returns Expression:
BitwiseAND ({BitwiseOR.left=current} name='|' right=BitwiseAND)*;

BitwiseAND returns Expression:
BitwiseXOR ({BitwiseAND.left=current} name='&' right=BitwiseXOR)*;

BitwiseXOR returns Expression:
Addition ({BitwiseXOR.left=current} name='^' right=Addition)*;

Addition returns Expression:
Substraction ({Addition.left=current} name='+' right=Substraction)*;

Substraction returns Expression:
Multiplication ({Substraction.left=current} name='-' right=Multiplication)*;

Multiplication returns Expression:
Division ({Multiplication.left=current} name='*' right=Division)*;

Division returns Expression:
Modulo ({Division.left=current} name='/' right=Modulo)*;

Modulo returns Expression:
Primary ({Modulo.left=current} name='%' right=Primary)*;

Primary returns Expression:
=> count=count
| => func=funccall
| {Bracket} '(' inner=Expression ')'
| (name=unop) expr=Expression
| (name=unop)? ID=Literal ('IS' 'NOT'? 'NULL')?;

/*Values that a Expression can have */
Literal returns Expression: 
value=values;
```

I can manage to get to get a single value but im unable to get the left or the right side of a expression.

My Generator (unfinished and with my testings looks like this)

```
class TsqlGenerator extends AbstractGenerator {
StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
TimeConditionHandler tch = new TimeConditionHandler
ExpressionHandler exprH = new ExpressionHandler
String expression = ""
int fromIndex = 0;
int whereIndex


def clear() {
    st.delete(0, st.length);
    fromIndex = 0;
    whereIndex =0;

}

override beforeGenerate(Resource input, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) { clear() }

override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {

    for (e : resource.allContents.toIterable.filter(ComplexSelect)) {

        /*SELECT */
        // TODO: String Value ohne Anführungszeichen?
        st.append("SELECT ");
        for (selectArgument : e.left.selectArguments.arguments) {
            if (selectArgument.expr.name == null) {
                //hier später in eine Liste speichern?
                    st.append(" " + selectArgument.expr.ID.value.name);
            }else {
                // TODO: Generate a Sting of the Expression!

            }
        }

        /*FROM */
        st.append(" FROM ")
        //Hier ebenso in eine Liste speichern?
        for (fromSource : e.left.from.sources) {
                st.append(e.left.from.sources.get(fromIndex).name);
        }

        /*WHERE */
        if (e.left.where !== null || e.left.timedef !== null) {
            st.append(" WHERE");

            if (e.left.where !== null) {
                for (whereArgument : e.left.where.predicates.expr) {
                    if (whereIndex == 0) {
                        st.append(" " + whereArgument.ID.value.name);
                    } else {
                        st.append("AND " + whereArgument.ID.value.name);
                    }
                    whereIndex++;
                }
            }
            /*TIMEINTERVALL 
             *TODO: timestamp as columname hardcoded*/
            if (e.left.timedef !== null) {
                if (whereIndex > 0) {
                    st.append(" AND")
                }
                st.append(tch.toIso8601(e.left.timedef))
                //if (e.left.timedef.name != null) {
                //st.append(" ").append(e.left.where.name);
            }
            }



        fsa.generateFile("query.txt", st.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Posting generator code may help. But if you are trying to getLeft on actual Expression type that is because Expression is more a base class without fields from which the other classes extend. If Expression was a Literal you would not expect it to have a left field. Instead you would check the actual type of the Expression, cast, and make your call accordingly

Comment: I added my codegenerator

Comment: So in that generator `e` is an instance of `ComplexSelect` correct? I don't see where you are trying to use `getLeft` or `getRight` on an `Expression` instance. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question

Comment: As a misc suggestion, have you looked into xtend's templating syntax? Really handy for generation

Comment: Right e is the instance.
In the Select Statement i at first use this line selectArgument.expr.ID.value.name to get the value 
But it only works if i have a single value 
if i have the statement: SELECT x + y FROM XYZ  i still get x but i want to use getLeft and getRight because i could get the value of left(x) and right(y) there.

Comment: Okay then the cause is probably the grammar ambiguity A.H. stated. To be sure you can debug and check the abstract syntax tree and make sure it is what you expect, but my guess is that it won't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following simplified grammar

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl1.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl1/MyDsl"

Model:
    (expressions+=Expression ";")*;

Expression returns Expression:
    OrExpression;

OrExpression returns Expression:
    PrimaryExpression ({OrExpression.left=current} name="OR" right=PrimaryExpression)*;

PrimaryExpression returns Expression:
     '(' Expression ')'
    | {Negation} "NOT" expr=Expression 
    | {IntLiteral} value=INT
    | {StringLiteral} value=STRING
    | {Variable} name=ID;
```

the input `NOT x or y` can be parsed in two ways: Either as

```
Or(Negation(Variable("x")), Variable("y"))
```

or as

```
Negation(Or(Variable("x"), Variable("y")))
```

When compiling the Xtext grammer it tells you so (somewhat vaguely) with warnings likes this:

```
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl1/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl1/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:195:3: Decision can match input such as "'OR'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

The important part here is: `[...]alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input`. So parts of your grammar are dead code and effectively ignored.

Solution: Put **all** operators into the precedence hierarchy properly. Do **not** put anything complex into `PrimaryExpression`. In fact `( Expression )` 
should be the **only** place which calls a rule higher in the hierarchy. The result is a conflict-free grammar like this:

```
OrExpression returns Expression:
    IsNullExpression ({OrExpression.left=current} name="OR" right=IsNullExpression)*;

IsNullExpression returns Expression:
    CompareExpression ({IsNullExpression.expr=current} 'IS' not?='NOT'? 'NULL')?;

CompareExpression returns Expression:
    NegationExpression ({CompareExpression.left=current} name=("NOT"| "=" | "!=") right=NegationExpression)*;

NegationExpression returns Expression:
    {NegationExpression} name=("NOT" | "-") expr=PrimaryExpression
    | PrimaryExpression;

PrimaryExpression returns Expression:
     '(' Expression ')'
    | {IntLiteral} name=INT
    | {StringLiteral} name=STRING
    | {Variable} name=ID;
```

Note that this grammar is conflict free despite several keywords are used multiple times in distinct places (e.g. `NOT`, `-`).

Comment: Hey yeah you are right i get this kind of warnings.
But i want to use them in different contexts.
1. as a way to supress A NOT B means A != B 
2. Negation with a "-" what is defined in my unop operations 
But the warnings come form the double statement of the "-" for unop and for substrachtion

Comment: You don't get the point: Your line `(name=unop) expr=Expression` calls an "upper" rule and allows ambiguous syntax. This happens **even** if there is **no** double usage of a keyword like `NOT` (see my first simple grammar). Therefore you **must** solve this first. **Then** you can proceed to enhance the syntax with `x NOT y` and `-x`. And then you have to do the same thing again: define proper precedence rules which avoids ambiguity. You simply cannot ignore this kind of warnings AND get a working grammar.

Comment: I implemented it as you said and the warnings are gone but now i cant use the "-" anymore.
It also tells me that there are multiple ways to reach the "-" and it cant decide so also alternatives are again disabled.
I dont understand how i can manage it otherwise.

Comment: Sorry i was busy but i managed to implement it like you show it in your comment
Thank you for your help!